How to Process Responses from OpenAI API Without Encountering 'ChatCompletionChunk' Object Not Subscriptable Error?
I am using the OpenAI GPT-4 Turbo model via the OpenAI Python SDK to generate chat completions. However, I'm running into an issue where I get a 'ChatCompletionChunk' object is not subscriptable error when trying to access message contents from the response. Below is the snippet of code I'm using:
def call_openai(prompt):
    try:
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-4-turbo",
            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
            stream=True
        )
        messages = []
        
        for message in response:
            if message['role'] == 'assistant':
                messages.append(message['content'])
        
        return " ".join(messages)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

In this code, I expect to collect and concatenate messages from the assistant role, but the error suggests that the objects returned are not directly subscriptable. It seems there is a misunderstanding on my part regarding the object structure returned by chat.completions.create.
What is the correct way to access the messages from the response object?
Could anyone provide or point me to detailed documentation or examples for handling responses from chat.completions.create with stream=False in the OpenAI Python SDK?
